# Handling external links in Wordpress in a central - without cloaking

Tags: seo, wordpress, hyperlink

I am happily using the plugin LinkHopper in Wordpress for my affiliate websites. It makes it easy for me to keep track of all external links in one place. Especially since I have tracking links that needs to be changed once in a while and changing link url's on each page would be a great hassle.

So, so far so good.

**The current solution**

Now, I have discovered this is not the best thing according to Google guidelines since each external link will look like this:

www.mydomain.com/out/this-particular-external-link/

which might lead to www.youtube.com for example.

**The problem**

Google index /out/this-particular-external-link/ as a page on my website, which it obviously isn't.

I have solved this by blocking all /out/* in my robots.txt but appearantly it's not too great blocking that many pages in Googles eyes ("what are you hiding from us?").

**The question**

So, I still need this centralized way of handling links but I would like the url's uncloaked so Google understands it's an external link.

Are there any better plugins that I don't know about?
Is there a different approach that would solve this problem?

Comment: The `robots.txt` solution seems the best one to me. Also read http://yoast.com/cloak-affiliate-links/

Comment: Thanks, but according to my SEO-consultant this is not something Google likes very much. Hiding things from the search engines is never a good idea, I think...